# Completed PDF Form Not Attaching to Email

Tags: java, pdf

I have a PDF application that I created for application submittals.  In the sheet there is a button to submit the application using the code below.

```
var theSubject = this.getField("SOM_SITE_NUM_2").value;
this.mailDoc({
   cTo: "emaildestination@domain.COM",
   cSubject: theSubject + ' Application Submittal',
})
```

When testing the sheet and button, the button press does as expected.  Opens an email, fills into the destination email and subject line, and attaches a copy of the completed form.  When uploading this pdf to our online site and testing the button press, it opens an email, fills into the destination email and subject line, but does NOT attach a copy of the completed form.  I am guessing that since it is not running from a local file anymore that this is why the completed form is not attaching.   Could someone with more knowledge than I help me out with what coding needs to be added so that the completed form will attach?

So far I have tried some other code found online and added it to the button press but nothing has worked to get the button press to include the completed form in the online version.